# Inequalities relating $S_n$ and $T_n$

Tags: calculus

> $$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{n}{n^2 + kn + k^2}$$  $$T_n =
>  \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{n}{n^2 + kn + k^2} $$
>
> a) $S_n < \dfrac{\pi}{3\sqrt 3}$
>
> b) $S_n> \dfrac{\pi}{3 \sqrt 3}$
>
> c) $T_n< \dfrac{\pi}{3\sqrt 3}$
>
> d) $T_n > \dfrac{\pi}{3\sqrt 3}$

My Attempt:

We can say that: $$\lim_{n \to \infty}S_n = \displaystyle\int_{0}^1\dfrac{1}{1+x+x^2}= \dfrac{\pi}{3\sqrt 3}$$

But I am not really sure about the concept used to solve this problem. I need help with that—the concept (not the answer).

How can we relate $S_n$  to the integral's value without knowing anything else?

Comment: Hint: Since the terms of summation are always positive so the infinite summation will be always greater than the finite summation( in your case by first determining the upper and lower sum if Riemann sum to integral form)

Comment: Have you learnt that the integral can be approximated by upper sum and lower sum? Hint: Try to observe which of $S_n$ and $T_n$ is upper sum (resp., lower sum).

Comment: Also note that $$S_n-T_n=\frac {-2}{3n}$$  I think the above two points are more than enough to solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should notice that $S_n$ represents the **Right** Riemann Sum. Here, every small rectangle takes its height according to the right endpoint of each interval. On the contrary, $T_n$ represents the **Left** Riemann Sum. Here, every small rectangle takes its height according to the left startpoint of each interval.

But $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x+x^2}$ is decreasing over $[0,1].$ So, the height of every  small rectangle among $S_n$ is shorter than that among $T_n$ over the same interval. Hence, we can have that $$S_n<\int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{1+x+x^2}<T_n.$$

[image]

[image]